# Adding Code behind to compiled asp.net web site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have inherited a web site that doesn't have code behind source files, only the compiled version of the files. Is there an "easy" way to add code behind files and get it to compile? The source project was lost and all I have to use is the compiled site.

Comment: Here is a great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854545/convert-a-single-file-aspx-to-code-behind/1770165#1770165. Otherwise you'll need a decompiler.

Comment: You could try dotPeek from JetBrains to decompile it into a new project: http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/index.html?topDP